# convert Set by List.of or ArrayList?

Tags: java, collections

I want to convert a set to a list. Which method should I prefer (I dont care if it's immutable or not):

**version 1:**

```
return List.of(myHashSet().toArray());
```

**or version 2:**

```
return new ArrayList<Strategy>(myHashSet());
```

Are there any other differences besides that version 1 is immutable? For example, `List.of` is more space efficient in compare to ArrayList.

Comment: "*For example, List.of is more space efficient in compare to ArrayList*" why? First version `List.of(myHashSet().toArray());` needs to create additional array, so it takes more memory.

Comment: Good point. According to Java Docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/core/creating-immutable-lists-sets-and-maps.htm#JSCOR-GUID-6A9BAE41-A1AD-4AA1-AF1A-A8FC99A14199 I preferred `List.of()` but, you  are right, it must be converted `toArray()` which eliminates the space/memory benefits of `List.of()`.

Comment: `List.copyOf(myHashSet())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only differences I see between your 1 and 2 are:

- [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)) produces a shallowly immutable list. You cannot add or remove items from the list. Of course, the state within each object contained in the list would still be mutable if already so. Your # 1 results in an immutable list while the [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) of # 2 is mutable.
- With # 2, you know and control the concrete class of the resulting `List`. With # 1, you neither know nor control the concrete class used behind the scenes when calling `List.of`. The `List.of` feature is free to use any class that implements `List` interface, possibly even a class not publicly available with the Java Collections Framework. The `List.of` feature might even be smart about choosing an optimized class appropriate to your particular collected objects.

You said:

> List.of is more space efficient in compare to ArrayList.

You cannot make that claim, if you mean usage of memory (RAM). As discussed above, you neither know nor control the choice of class used to implement `List` interface when calling `List.of`. The class used might vary depending on your data, and might vary by version of Java used at runtime.

As for memory used by the call to `toArray`, an array of objects is really just an array of references (pointers). Creating that array takes little memory and is fast. Object references are likely to be a value of four or eight octets (depending on your [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) being 32-bit or 64-bit), though not specified by Java. In creating the array, it is *not* as if the content of your element objects are being duplicated. So for most common apps the brief creation and disposal of that array would be insignificant.

And, as [commented by Kuhn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490302/convert-set-by-list-of-or-arraylist/61490946#comment108774722_61490302), Java 10 saw the arrival of a new factory method [`List.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)) that takes a `Collection`. So no need to call `toArray`.

```
List<Strategy> myStrategyList = List.copyOf( myStrategySet ) ;
```

Conclusion:

- If you need an immutable list, use `List.copyOf`.
- If your need mutability or any other feature specific to a particular
  implementation of `List`, use that particular class.

Comment: You should also mention the rigid behavior regarding `null`. `List.of(…)` does not only disallow `null` as element, it will also throw exceptions on queries like `contains(null)`. You must be able to cope with that when using these immutable lists. Further, the array created by `toArray()` when using `List.of(myHashSet().toArray())` is only temporary. While the actual implementation is unspecified, the immutable lists are more space efficient in practice, in some scenarios.